# User-input string saved as URL in app preferences

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, preferences

I have a very simple app. It has a tab bar controller with two web views, `webView1` and `webView2`. I can push websites to both of my views. I would like to add a simple text field where a user can type in a string and it plugs that string into a URL.  I would also like to set that string as the default for both of my web views.

For example, the user enters "questions" and it inputs it into the string `@"http://www.stackoverflow.com/"STRING""`. This will set the default string as "questions" and everytime the app loads it will display the URL. Can anyone shed some light on this for me?

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to use the defaults system to store a user default. When a user enters the default string, you could do something like:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:theString forKey:@"defaultURLString"]
```

To save the string for the next time the app launches, do the following:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

When your app loads, you would then retrieve this string using:

```
NSString *theString = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectforKey:@"defaultURLString"]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the same string int he URL every time the app loads(or you change the string), I suggest you look into NSUserDefaults. Here is [something](http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/10/03/iphone-programming-tutorial-savingretrieving-data-using-nsuserdefaults/) to help you get started:

Hope it helps.